# Why can i initialize a plain array using a list without using assignment operator

Tags: c++, c, arrays, initialization, operators

I find in someone's code that we can initialize a plain c style array in C++ using a list without actually using the assignment operator. The code is like this:

```
int a[4]{1, 2, 3, 4};
for (int i =0; i < 4; i++){
    cout << a[i] << '\n';
}
```

The above code runs correctly. The above initialization is like how we initialize a vector of int in C++. I try to use this in C. But it is not permitted.

Why can we do this in C++ but not in C? Since when can we use this kind of initialization syntax for plain C++ array? Can you give any references to this syntax? I do not know where to find it.

Comment: Because C and C++ are *different languages*? Even though they share a common root, and have some similar syntax, they are still not the same.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think ^ that should be the answer

Comment: *"Since when can we use this kind of initialization syntax for plain C++ array?"* - Since 2011, if not earlier

Comment: It's called [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

Comment: An initialiser in C also does not use the assignment operator! In something like `int i = 10, k;` `=` is not assignment operator, as much as the comma is not the comma operator.

Comment: @Olaf, then what should we call the `=` in `int i = 10;`? I just do not know the exact jargon to use in this case.

Comment: @jdhao: How do you call the `;`? It is a symbol, introducing the initialiser! An initialiser is **not** an assignment! That's why `int a[] = {1,2,3};` is valid, but `a = {1,2,3}` is not (disclaimer: simplified example)! The only point you have to understand is that different languages have different syntax and semantics! Would you expect Python to accept the code above? No? Why C then?

Comment: @Olaf, indeed it is not assignment. What do you think is the best way to call it? Just that character? I am trying to specific so that people can understand my question.

Answer (score 2):

> Why can we do this in C++ but not in C?

C++ and C are different languages. In C, the `=` is required. In C++ (since C++11), it is optional.

In C++, it is called [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), which has the following syntax:

```
T object = {arg1, arg2, ...};
T object {arg1, arg2, ...};     // (since C++11)
```

For further details: see section **8.5.1 Aggregates [dcl.init.aggr]** in the C++ specification.

Answer (score 1):

In C the initialization has fixed one form

```
init-declarator:
    declarator
    declarator = initializer 
              ^^^
```

In C++ there are various forms of initialization with different semantics.

In C++ the initialization is subdivided in initializations with copy-initialization semantic and direct-initialization semantic.

For example these initializations for a non-aggregate type `A`

```
A a = { 10 }; // copy-initialization
```

and

```
A a { 10 }; // direct-initialization
```

can produce different results depending on whether the corresponding constructor is explicit or non-explicit.

Consider the following program

```
int main()
{
    struct A
    {
        explicit A(int x) : x(x) {}

        int x;
    };

    A a1 { 1 };
    // A a2 = { 1 }; - compilation error
}
```

Moreover In C++ there are also initializer lists and initializer-list constructors.

Modify the previous demonstrative program the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
    struct A
    {
        explicit A(int x) : x(x) 
        {
            std::wcout << "A::A( int )" << std::endl;
        }
        explicit A(std::initializer_list<int> lst) :
            x(std::accumulate(lst.begin(), lst.end(), 0)) 
        {
            std::wcout << "A::A( std::ininitializer_list<int> )" << std::endl;
        }
        int x;
    };

    A a { 1 };
}
```

and see its output.

In C there is no such a subdivision. It does not make sense because behind it there is no special semantic of initialization in C.

Introducing different forms of initialization without special semantics will only confuse users.